# How can I use a variable as a parameter in getSheetByName?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I have the following code which generates some gslides slides from data in a spreadsheet. The code is attached to the gslides file and it works when the parameters for link/year are entered as strings. However, these parameters will sometimes vary from a set list (e.g. pull from a different sheet or from a different file) so the code sometimes needs to be edited.

I want to share this with colleagues who don't know how to use app scripts and so tried to edit it so that the link/year can be pulled from a textbox in one of the slides in the gslides file. They are pulling through ok but when I try to use it as a parameter I get an error for line 11 (var values = sheet.getRange('F2:aa2').getValues();) as the sheet returns as null.

I've tried wrapping it in quotes (" ' " + year + " ' ") but that doesn't work either.

Please let me know if I need to include more info or a link to the sheets/slides files.

````
function generateStarters() {
                                                                               
  var deck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = deck.getSlides();
  var link = slides[2].getPageElements()[2].asShape().getText().asString()
  var year = slides[2].getPageElements()[4].asShape().getText().asString()
  var dataSpreadsheetUrl = link 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(dataSpreadsheetUrl);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(year); 
  var values = sheet.getRange('F2:aa2').getValues(); 

  var templateSlide = slides[1];
  var presLength = slides.length;
  
  values.forEach(function(page){
  if(page[0]){
    
   var Q1 = page[0];
   var A1 = page[1];
   var Q2 = page[4];
   var A2 = page[5];
   var Q3 = page[8];
   var A3 = page[9];
   var Q4 = page[12];
   var A4 = page[13];
   var QK = page[16];
   var AK = page[17]; 
   var QF = page[20];
   var AF = page[21];
    
   templateSlide.duplicate(); //duplicate the template page
   slides = deck.getSlides(); //update the slides array for indexes and length
   newSlide = slides[3]; // declare the new page to update
    
    
   var shapes = (newSlide.getShapes());
     shapes.forEach(function(shape){
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{q1}}',Q1);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{a1}}',A1);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{q2}}',Q2);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{a2}}',A2);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{q3}}',Q3);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{a3}}',A3);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{q4}}',Q4);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{a4}}',A4);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{qk}}',QK);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{ak}}',AK);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{qf}}',QF);
       shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{af}}',AF);
       
    }); 
   presLength = slides.length; 
   newSlide.move(presLength); 
  } 
  }); 
} ```
````

Comment: What the exact error?

Comment: My guess is that year is either undefined or it's not the name of a sheet. Or perhaps your sheet names have leading or trial spaces

Comment: The error is that var values = sheet.getRange('F2:aa2').getValues(); can't get values as the variable sheet returns as null.

I thought spaces might be the issue but I've even copied the sheet name straight into the textbox in the slides file with no change and when I get it from the logger it comes up correctly.

Comment: Well it's clear then that year is not a correct sheet name.  You should be able to use the debugger to determine what the problem is.  If you can't yet then it's probably time to step back and learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: The sheet name is Y7 Plan and when I type 'Y7 Plan' in as a parameter it works. I've copied that exactly into the textbox in the slides file and then checked using the logger that the variable year returns Y7 Plan as a string. The exact error is TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 10, file "Code") and when I click the debugger, thats the only error that pops up.

Comment: I guess I missed the fact that it could be that the link or the year is incorrect.  I would just single step through the script and figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, I've learned more about debugger now (this is my first ever code) and found that there is definitely a space appearing after the Y7 Plan. This seems to reappear even when I delete it from the textbox in gslides so I'm just going to shorten the string in my code by 1 character. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you can  use one of the [javascript trim commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)?

Comment: Yep, I went for: var year1 = year.substring(0, year.length - 1) as not all the sheet names are the same length.

Comment: @MathTeacher1 - please add what you commented in your answer below, the comments can be removed anytime

Answer (score 0):

The string from the slides file seems to always have a space at the end (from the textbox) so I just needed to add an extra line of code to remove that space.